# Getting the value of an id without tagging the DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a todo-list app, and for this sake I want to get the value of the id without tagging the DOM(`document.getElementById().value;`) because I've heard that jsx doesn't support that. I also used `event.target.value`, but that doesn't work because event is deprecated!

```
function listItems(taskName) {
    const tasks = [];
    tasks.push(taskName);

    console.log("Added " + taskName + " to the array!");
}


function CreateArea() {
    return (
        <div className="mainbox">
            <div className="inputdiv">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Task..." className="textbox" id="taskName"/>
                <button className="button" onClick={}>+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

P.S

I also used the arrow function, but I can't think of a way to tag the id without the DOM.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's many ways to do this sort of thing, but I think what you want here is [the `useRef` hook.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

In this case, the `ref` is an object that points to the input element after it gets rendered. You can then use that ref in other functions of your component.

For example:

```
function CreateArea() {
    const inputRef = useRef()

    function onClick() {
        listItems(listItemsinputRef.current.value)
    }

    return (
        <div className="mainbox">
            <div className="inputdiv">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  ref={inputRef} // tell the input element to use this ref.
                  placeholder="Enter Task..."
                  className="textbox"
                  id="taskName"
                />
                <button className="button" onClick={onClick}>+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I "tell the input element to use this ref"?

Comment: with `ref={inputRef}`. That's what the comment was intended to point out.